# Is this a cedar tree?

Tags: trees

Can the experts please help us identify this tree?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a photo showing a close up view of a 'leaf' so we can see the arrangement of needles round the stem please

Comment: Also the location as there are several cedars, junipers,tamaracks , etc.

Comment: Which tree do you want us to id?  The one in the foregrounds the main trunk we can see?  Or the limbs that fill up most of the photo, from what appears to be the tree in the background? The one in the foreground appears to be a pine.  It is not a cedar, neither cedrus or thuja.   The other one I can not make out from this distance.  Look on the ground for fallen leaves/needles to the tree that you want us to ID.  Then take picture of these needles.  Where are you located?  Is it a park or a the woods.  What part of the world?

Comment: @blacksmith37 This photo was taken in Lake Arrowhead, California USA.
Bamboo and GardenGems , I will add better and close up pictures when I get back to the area. Thanks!